# How to move object to position of another moving object in ARView?

Tags: xcode, object, position, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to add arrow like object_2 above object_1 to show user that object_1 is selected.
I'm loading object_2 and adding it as a child to tapped object_1.
Object_1 have installed gestures in view like that

```
arview.installGestures([.translation, .rotation], for: object_1)
```

Object_2 is placing correctly above object_1, but when I move object_1 with finger gesture - object_2 does not change position.
How to solve this? Maybe my approach is not correct. Or there is some update func, thats called every frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see how you're setting object_2. Are you setting it like object_1.addChild(object_2), or setting it relative to the position of object_1?

If setting it as a child, then it should be moving with object_1, otherwise you'll need to create a [scene publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene/3254685-publisher) for `SceneEvents.Update` to update the object position. You can optimise this slightly by only calling when a finger is on the screen.